# Prove there isn't an isomorphism between quotient polynomial rings

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, group-isomorphism

Prove there isn't an isomorphism
$$\phi: {{\mathbb Q [x]} \over {I_1}} \to {{\mathbb Q [x]} \over {I_2}}$$

when $I_1=\langle x^2-2\rangle$, $I_2=\langle x^2+2\rangle$.

I want to assume there is an isomorphism, and say $\phi(1+I_1)=1+I_2$ so $\phi(x^2-2+I_1)=x^2-2+I_2$, and to get a contradiction from here, but why is that true that $\phi(x^2-2+I_1)=x^2-2+I_2$?

Comment: That is not true, in fact $\phi(x^2-2) = x^2+2$. $0$ must be taken to $0$.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish oh.. and I thought I can get from that that 0 not taken to 0 and this is the contradiction...

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish so how can I prove this otherwise?

Comment: Both quotient rings are fields (i.e., $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$.)  The second field has an element of order $4$.  How about the first field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remark That $Q[X]/I_1=\{a+xb, a,b\in Q, x^2=2\}$ $Q[X]/I_2=\{a+yb, a,b\in Q, y^2=-2\}$.

Suppose $\phi$ exists, write $\phi(x)=a+by$, $\phi(x^2)=2=(a+by)^2=a^2-2b^2+2aby=2$. This implies $ab=0$. If $a=0$, $-2b^2=2$ impossible in $Q$.

Suppose that $b=0$, $a^2=2$ impossible in $Q$.

Comment: $x^2=2$ in $\mathbb Q[x] \over I_1$ but why $\phi(x^2)=2$

Comment: @ManoMini $$\phi(x^2)=\phi(2)=\phi(1+1)=\phi(1)+\phi(1)=1+1=2$$

Answer (score 0):

One very simple reason is that, if they were isomorphic, their rings of integers would be too. Now the ring of integers $\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2-2)$ has only two units – $\pm 1$, while  $\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2+2)$ has a group of units isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z$, by *Dirichlet's units theorem* . In any case, even without using this theorem, it has two other units: $\;\pm(3+2x)$.

Comment: Hmm, both are fields.

Comment: @egreg: Oops! I was thinking of the rings of integers. Thank you for pointing it. It's corrected now.